# How to get rid of chili-peppers on fingertips?

Tags: chili-peppers

When I cut chili-pepper, it takes more then a day for the chili to disappear from my fingertips. It is particularly hurtfull when I put in my contactlenses. Is there a way to get rid of this chili more quickly?

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32519/how-should-i-handle-chiles-without-gloves

Comment: @Jefromi I knew about that question and thought it was a closer duplicate, but I couldn't find it last night.

Answer (score 6):

Capsaicin, the active compound in chillies, isn't soluble in water so it's hard to wash off. As a contact lens wearer you might prefer to wear disposable gloves to prepare them. It is soluble in fats so my wife's approach (she wears lenses, I don't) is to rub olive oil into her hands, then wash with soap and water. It seems effective, and we've seen it recommended online (maybe even here) but we only use fairly mild chillies.

Comment: And whether you use oil or just wash really really thoroughly, I think it helps a little to do it right away, before it has time to soak in.

Comment: @Jefromi quite possibly. That also means you give them a really thorough wash while you remember

Comment: The eyes are so very sensitive that I've never managed to wash off enough oils. So gloves are a really good idea. (Though I usually use a fork to hold the chile instead.)

Comment: i use a mix of olive oil and honey. not sure where i read that, but it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I use the some olive oil on your finger tips trick.  I takes away like 90% of the problem for me.  A friend mine taught it to me that grows some killer peppers.

Answer (score 0):

Washing your hands in oil, then removing the oil with soap can help. As a last ditch option, consider bleach (however it works - it does).